# Symmetric power subspace of tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Consider the symmetric power $S^d(\mathbb{C}^2)$. This can be identified with the space of degree $d$ homogeneous polynomials in $x$ and $y$.

Can $S^d(\mathbb{C}^2)$ be considered as a subspace of some tensor power? I understand $S^d(\mathbb{C}^2) = T^d(\mathbb{C}^2)/I$ where $T^d(\mathbb{C}^2)$ is the $d$-th tensor power, but I was told that $S^d(\mathbb{C}^2)$ is a subspace of a tensor power ``spanned by symmetrized tensors.'' What does this mean?

Comment: Have you seen the tensor product of vector spaces or modules?  That is, are you used to objects of the form $u \otimes v \otimes w$ for "vectors" $u,v,w$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short and sweet answer:

The space $T^d(\Bbb C^2)$ can be identified with the space of degree $d$ homogeneous polynomials with complex coefficients in **non-commuting variables** $x$ and $y$.  That is, we have $xyx - x^2y \neq 0$.  As you might expect, this gives us a $2^d$-dimensional space.

*Symmetrizing* tensors, then, is tantamount to allowing the variables $x$ and $y$ to commute.

Comment: The boldfaced title seems a bit unnecessary.

Comment: @Pedro I had planned on a second section at the time. I agree, though.

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably looking for is the embedding $\text{Sym}^d V\to T^d(V)$ given by $v_1\otimes \ldots \otimes v_d \mapsto \sum_{\sigma \in S_d} \sigma(v_1)\otimes \ldots \ldots \sigma(v_d)$. (Actually typically we divide by $d!$ as well.) It should be apparent this is an embedding by writing out things in terms of basis elements.

The fact that this exists, in a pretty natural way, should've been apparent from your construction of the symmetric power as quotient: recall that every quotient of a vector space is also a subspace once you split the right arrow in the corresponding short exact sequence, which in this case is just
$$0\to \text{span}\left(v_1\otimes \ldots \otimes v_d - \sigma(v_1)\otimes \ldots \otimes \sigma(v_d)\right) \to T^d(V) \to \text{Sym}^d(V)\to 0$$
where the left span is over transpositions $\sigma$. (We divide by $d!$ to make this a genuine splitting.)

Indeed when $d=2$, the corresponding left split (the "reversed" short exact sequence) gives us basically the same thing for the object on the left, which is the exterior power $\wedge^2V$, which we now see can also be viewed as both a subspace and a quotient in a very similar way to the symmmetric power. Further, in this way, we get the natural decomposition of a rank-two tensor into symmetric and antisymmetric parts, which is very important (not to mention clean-looking).

We don't get this same direct sum decomposition when $d>2$ (the dimensions couldn't possibly work), but exterior powers are also similarly both a quotient and a subspace in a dual-ish way. When considered as subspaces, we talk about "symmetric and anti-symmetric tensors," and when considered as a quotient, we talk about symmetric and exterior powers.